# networkx: json_graph.node_link_data substitution example

Tags: json, networkx

<strike>In networkx v1.9 networkx.readwrite.json_graph api was removed</strike> [1]. We still find references to this package and especially the node_link_data function in numerous examples and tutorials. What puzzled me was that, although this package was removed, you still find documentation for the package in v1.9 and succeeding versions [2].

I'm looking for an example of how to substitute for json_graph.node_link_data with functions from the standard library.

[1] http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api_1.9.html#miscellaneous-changes
[2] http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/readwrite.json_graph.html?highlight=networkx.readwrite.#module-networkx.readwrite.json_graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found, the package is not removed.  It still exists in networkx.  There is an example on how to use it at the link you provided http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.json_graph.node_link_data.html#networkx.readwrite.json_graph.node_link_data

Comment: Confirmed. What made me think that the package was removed is the changelog + this ipython3 error: `----> 1 data = networkx.readwrite.json_graph.node_link_data(G)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'json_graph'`. Because of some weired reason (my) ipython can't find the package.

Comment: Did you solve this?  I have the same version of WinPython with networkX 2.* installed on three computers, but one of them gives me this error running the same code.