# Open json graph in NetworkX yields "module 'networkx' has no attribute 'json_graph' "

Tags: python, json, networkx

I have the code below for importing graphs saved as JSONs, and it works perfectly on 2 of 3 computers, all running the same WinPython v3.6.  On the third computer it returns: `AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'json_graph'`.

```
import json
import networkx as nx

def openJSONDiGraph(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    js_graph = json.load(f)
return nx.json_graph.node_link_graph(js_graph, directed=True, multigraph=False)

thisNetwork = openJSONDiGraph(networkFileAddress)
```

This code has worked perfectly for two years to import graphs saved as JSON.  It previously worked on this computer too, but I had to reinstall my whole Python (using the same exact installer) recently, and now it fails.

This is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665042/read-json-graph-networkx-file), so I tried to include `from networkx.readwrite import json_graph` instead, but this returns `ImportError: cannot import name 'to_tuple'`.  Making me think there is something wrong with my NetworkX installation or its dependencies.

I uninstalled and reinstalled NetworkX 2.4 using pip (the other computers are running v2.1, but that shouldn't make a difference here), and the problem persists.

This question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966659/networkx-json-graph-node-link-data-substitution-example), but there is no solution posted there.

How do I fix my NetworkX installation or change my code to get this to work as it usually does?

Comment: Could you add the full error traceback for the `from networkx.readwrite import json_graph` import? I tried it on my setting (networkx 2.4) and the import did not raised an error.

Answer (score 1):

Without anything else to try, and contrary to my expectations, downgrading from NetworkX v2.4 to v2.1 solved this problem.  I didn't see anything in the v2.4 documentation that suggested this would be different, but clearly something in the readwrite module has changed.

I could delete the question at this point, but I think it's better to leave it here for posterity in case anybody confronts similar issues while trying to upgrade.